# Eloquent Update Class Object

Tags: eloquent

I have following eloquent statement which works.

```
GroupRequest::where([['iduser', 1],['idgroups', $request->input('idgroup')]])->update(['request_active' => 0]);
```

But I need it in a different way. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$groups_request = new GroupRequest();
$groups_request->idgroups::where([['iduser',1],['idgroups',$request->input('idgroup')]]);
$groups_request->update(['request_active' => 0]);
```

What's wrong with my below code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong code is **$groups_request->idgroups::where** . Corrected code is

```
$groups_request = new GroupRequest();
$groups_request->where([
    ['iduser',1],
    ['idgroups',$request->input('idgroup')]
])->update(['request_active' => 0]);
```